# Categories/Interfaces From Static Libs Not Autocompleting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Thanks to [this post](http://jeffreysambells.com/iphone-os-static-library-template/) and the now built-in static library template, I am able to put some of the pieces of my project elsewhere. Everything compiles with no warnings and runs fine. However, I used to get autocomplete for the categories in my import statement. This is no longer happening. How can I get autocomplete for categories in a static library?

Comment: Has anybody found a solution to this?

Comment: @LordT WYSIWYG: I gave up and used the classes in my project :(

Comment: @LordT, a solution has been found. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that XCode doesn't know where to look for your header files.

To fix this, do the following - In the **"User Header Search Paths"** of your app's target, point to the location of your category header. That tells XCode where to look for it, and autocomplete should work. In case of multiple targets, you could fix it for each target or at the project's settings.

Comment: @Tejas, I've currently given up on this thing and don't have time to test it. However, I'm sure that @ludwigschubert might be interested (since he has a bounty on this Q). This answer definitely sounds promising, so +1 for now.

Comment: @Tejas Thank you! What you described works perfectly. The trick is that it does *not* work to add your Library to your "Header Search Paths", you have to add it to "**User** Header Search Paths". Also, you can add it to your project if you multiple targets.

Comment: @Yar this **is** the right answer, you might want to accept it.

Comment: @ludwigschubert done, thanks for the guidance and interest in this question. @Tejas, could you clean up the answer a bit, please? For the sake of future generations and that...

Comment: I also had this problem.
U solved it now, I have for other linker flags the flags '-all_load' and '-Objc". For my project and the library. I set Always search user paths to YES and added to User header search paths $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR). The last one solves that you have to link to a project location on the disk that of course can change between macs

Answer (score 6):

Take the info of your project's 'Target'

Go to 'Other Linker Flags' and add '-all_load'.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DaveDeLong, xCode, neither seems to help. I have -ObjC -all_load and `-licucore` (for RegexLite).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it to reindex everything if you uncheck the "Indexing: Enable for all projects" box in the Code Sense section of XCode Preferences. After unchecking it, maybe quit XCode, reopen it, then recheck that option. According to the help, unchecking that option not only turns indexing off, but also discards the current index.

Comment: I've currently given up on this thing and don't have time to test it. However, I'm sure that @ludwigschubert might be interested (since he has a bounty on this Q).